# Python Selenium can't find element by Class Name and xpath

Tags: selenium

I try to use Selenium to perform click Download button at `Historical Data/Time and Sales Historical Data` section in webpage: https://www.sgx.com/research-education/derivatives.

I tried the code below:

```
sgxMainPageUrl = "https://www.sgx.com/research-education/derivatives"
# downloadButtonClassName = "sgx-button--primary"
downloadButtonXpath = "//widget-reports-derivatives-tick-and-trade-cancellation//button[contains(@class,'sgx-button--primary')]"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)
driver.get(sgxMainPageUrl)


# search = driver.find_element_by_class_name(downloadButtonClassName)
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath(downloadButtonXpath)
```

But it returns:

```
File "...\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//widget-reports-derivatives-tick-and-trade-cancellation//button[contains(@class,'sgx-button--primary')]"}
```

I read several post and they faced this problem because duplicate xpath but this xpath is unique. Please help me explain why, many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an `Accept cookies` button, you need to click first. after that you can use the below `xpath` to click on download button :

```
(//button[text()='Download'])[1]
```

**Code  :**

```
driver.get(sgxMainPageUrl)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class*='banner-acceptance-button']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//button[text()='Download'])[1]"))).click()
```

**Imports  :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add a wait to let the page loaded before accessing that element.
Try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, downloadButtonXpath))).click()
```